# Why is insert/delete on one array modifying another as well?

Tags: ruby, arrays, insert

I have a question about using `insert` and `delete_at` with arrays.  If I insert an element into an array (`arry`) and then store that value in a different variable (`temp`), why does the variable `temp` change after I use `delete_at` on `arry`?  Is there a way to store the value of the array with the insert object permanently?

Here is some sample code:

```
arry = [0,1,3,4]
# => [0, 1, 3, 4]
arry.insert(1,5)
# => [0, 5, 1, 3, 4]
temp = arry
# => [0, 5, 1, 3, 4]
arry.delete_at(1)
# => 5
temp
# => [0, 1, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 6):

When you assign an array to a new variable, the array itself is not copied but only reference to that array is set. If you want to save original array to new variable, you need to clone the array
You can do it via [dup](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Object.html#method-i-dup).

```
temp = arry.dup
```

Answer (score 1):

It happens because you make `temp` variable pointing at the same object as `arry` variable. To do what you want, you should make copy of this object:

```
temp = arry.dup
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm just feeling in a right mood to tell something more than previous commenters, because some time ago I've had nearly the same headache with all this pass-reference-by-value stuff. So:

Ruby's variables are actually references to underlying objects inside Ruby's virtual machine. They are passed into functions 'by value', which means when you do `function(arg)`, `function` actually gets *copy of reference* to the memory object. So, `function` gets a valid reference to object, which `arg` and copy of `arg` reference. When you perform some actions on object referenced by `arg` or it's copy, you successfully modify *directly* that object. (But when you operate *directly* on references, things happen only to references, hence, copied reference inside function may even be deleted, which doesn't affect original reference or object. Consider this:

```
array_ref0 = [1,2,3] # actually, this reference represents array
array_ref1 = array_ref0
def f(arg); arg[0] = 0; end
f(array_ref0)
p array_ref0 # => [0,2,3]
p array_ref1 # => [0,2,3]
array_ref0 = [1,2,3]
p array_ref0 # => [1,2,3]
#but!
p array_ref1 # => [0,2,3]
```

That's because saying `array_ref0 = [1,2,3]` you reassigned the reference to a new object, but array_ref1 still references the old object, which is alive because >=1 references  reference to it (not going to talk much about GC here)

```
def g(arg); arg = nil; end
g(array_ref0)
p array_ref0 # => [1,2,3], because we only nil-ed copy of array_ref0.
```

Hope that cleared things a little.

I'm not telling you to #dup your array because previous commenters gave you comprehensive practical answers.